# Is there a method to get default network interface on local using python3?

Tags: python, networking, routes, python-3.3

Hi I want to get the default network interface using Python.
After google, I got `pynetinfo` can do this. But `pynetinfo` seems not work on Python3.
Is there another method to instead `pynetinfo`?

Comment: What do you mean by "default"? When sending a packet, the kernel decides on which interface to place the packet according to the routing table, by the given destination ip address. Did you mean "default" as in the interface that relays packets to the `default gateway`?

Comment: Yes,micromosesless.Thank you a lot for your response. “default gateway" is what I want to express. Can do me a favour?

Comment: Do you want to emulate `ip route list | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f3` in Python?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Linux you can examining the route table directly on `/proc/net/route`. This file contains the routing parameters of your system, here is an example:

```
Iface   Destination Gateway     Flags   RefCnt  Use Metric  Mask        MTU Window  IRTT
eth1    0009C80A    00000000    0001    0       0   0       00FFFFFF    0   0       0
eth2    0000790A    00000000    0001    0       0   0       0080FFFF    0   0       0
eth3    00007A0A    00000000    0001    0       0   0       0080FFFF    0   0       0
eth0    00000000    FE09C80A    0003    0       0   0       00000000    0   0       0
```

In this example all traffic to networks 10.200.9.0/24, 10.121.0.0/25 and 10.122.0.0/25 is broadcasted via eth1, eth2 and eth3 respectively, the rest of packages are sent using eth0 interface to the gateway 10.200.9.254. So the question is how to get this programatically using Python?

```
def get_default_iface_name_linux():
    route = "/proc/net/route"
    with open(route) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            try:
                iface, dest, _, flags, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, =  line.strip().split()
                if dest != '00000000' or not int(flags, 16) & 2:
                    continue
                return iface
            except:
                continue

get_default_iface_name_linux() # will return eth0 in our example
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you checking `or not int(flags, 16) & 2`?

Answer (score 5):

with [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2):

```
from pyroute2 import IPDB
ip = IPDB()
# interface index:
print(ip.routes['default']['oif'])
# interface details:
print(ip.interfaces[ip.routes['default']['oif']])
# release DB
ip.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both provided answers don't address Windows.
In Windows I would suggest using PowerShell.

The script below provides source IP address for default network interface (I.E. interface which routes traffic to 0.0.0.0/0):

```
from subprocess import check_output
src_ip = check_output((
        "powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command ""& {"
        "Get-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Select-Object -First 1 | "
        "Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress"
        "}"""
    )).decode().strip()
print(src_ip)
```

The same for the default network interface itself:

```
check_output((
    "powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command ""& {"
    "Get-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Select-Object -First 1 | "
    "Get-NetIPConfiguration"
    "}"""
)).decode().strip()
```